# Java - Trouble with brackets

Tags: java, brackets

I am having some trouble with the placing of brackets. I wanted to write a few methods within the confines of my main method, but I always end up with with a bunch of red lines and errors telling me "Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token "void", @ expected
    - addVehicleBooking cannot be resolved to a type"

I don't want my methods to return anything, I just want them to execute some code and print some stuff on the screen.

**EDIT:**

This is the start of the code, no need to worry about unused variables and such. Thanks for everyone's help =].

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FerryMenu {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void addVehicleBooking()
    {
        String booking_ID = "";
        System.out.print("Enter your booking ID");
        booking_ID = input.next();
        String registration = "";
        System.out.print("Enter registration number");
        registration = input.next();
        String make_model = "";
        System.out.print("Enter vehicle make/model");
        make_model = input.next();
        int number_passengers = 1;
        System.out.print("Enter number of passengers");
        number_passengers = scan.nextInt();
    }

    String menu_choice = "";
    while(!"X".equals(menu_choice)){
        System.out.println("*** Ferry Ticketing System Menu ***");
        System.out.println("A   -   Add Vehicle Booking");
        System.out.println("B   -   Display Booking Info");
        System.out.println("C   -   Update Insurance Status");
        System.out.println("D   -   Display Booking Summary");
        System.out.println("X   -   Exit");

        System.out.print("Enter your selection: ");
        menu_choice = input.next();     
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't declare methods inside a method.. It's not about brackets.. It's about syntax.

Ok, Dean, here I'll describe it once again..

First thing, `throw away` the code that you have written.. Lets start fresh..

Follow these steps to approach your problem: -

- Create a class say `Demo`
- Add a method to that class, `getUserInput()`
- Add main method also to your class.
- Have a constructor (0-arg)
- Now, your program starts executing from `main()`.. If you want to take user input.. Call your `getUserInput()` method from here.. As the first statement..
- In your `getUserInputMethod()`, after reading all the input, invoke your constructor to initialize your `instance variables`..
- After this, your `getUserInput()` will return control to your `main()` method.. You can proceed with your code from there..

Comment: not only that, addVehicleBooking is never used anyway so we can't guess what he needs to do with his "inner" method

Comment: @TecHunter: My guess was- if he declared there, may be that's where he wanted to call it.

Comment: @TecHunter.. Actually he has asked this question before.. There he had all those code inside a constructor. I told him to have a method, and let it do all the I/O.. And then you can create class instance from there... May be he's a little confused with that..

Comment: This is a different spec i'm working on, but following the same ideas.

Comment: @Dean.. OK.. haha. And actually I re-described your previous example in my current post.. I thought it was same as every thing looked same.. Instance variables and all that..

Comment: @Dean.. Anyway I'll leave it as it is.. May be it can help you in your current specs..

Answer (score 3):

You can not define a method inside a method. Declare it outside the method and inside the class.

```
public class FerryMenu {

    public static void addVehicleBooking()  
    {
         //...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)   
    {   
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);   
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);  

         // just call the method here
         addVehicleBooking();

         //...
    }
}
```

Comment: you cant define a method .. not you can ..:P

Comment: @chaitanya10: Oops! :o ... fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you are writing your addvehicalBooking method inside your main method. 
thus those red line :remove that method from main.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
}
    public static void addVehicleBooking()
    {
        String booking_ID = "";
        System.out.print("Enter your booking ID");
        booking_ID = input.next();
        String registration = "";
        System.out.print("Enter registration number");
        registration = input.next();
        String make_model = "";
        System.out.print("Enter vehicle make/model");
        make_model = input.next();
        int number_passengers = 1;
        System.out.print("Enter number of passengers");
        number_passengers = scan.nextInt();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out `addVehicleBooking()`  outside main and call it and declare the variables in a constructor

Answer (score 0):

You have a static method inside your main static method which is probably causing the problems.  Have you tried moving the addVehicleBooking() method to the space between public class FerryMenu and the main method?  (the addVehicleBooking() method should be a member of the class FerryMenu, not the main method)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you making a static method inside public static void main. I dont think that there is a need to make it.

Remove the word static from "static void addVehicleBooking".
I'll edit this answer and add the corrected code asap.

Answer (score 0):

you can not define method in method.
you can define it in class like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FerryMenu {

static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void addVehicleBooking()
{
    String booking_ID = "";
    System.out.print("Enter your booking ID");
    booking_ID = input.next();
    String registration = "";
    System.out.print("Enter registration number");
    registration = input.next();
    String make_model = "";
    System.out.print("Enter vehicle make/model");
    make_model = input.next();
    int number_passengers = 1;
    System.out.print("Enter number of passengers");
    number_passengers = scan.nextInt();
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{


    String menu_choice = "";
    while(!"X".equals(menu_choice)){
        System.out.println("*** Ferry Ticketing System Menu ***");
        System.out.println("A   -   Add Vehicle Booking");
        System.out.println("B   -   Display Booking Info");
        System.out.println("C   -   Update Insurance Status");
        System.out.println("D   -   Display Booking Summary");
        System.out.println("X   -   Exit");

        System.out.print("Enter your selection: ");
        menu_choice = input.next();     
    }
}
}
```

and fields "*input*" and "*scan*" must be defined as *static* because you are invoking them as static

Answer (score 0):

The `addVehicleBooking` should be placed outside `main`. BTW: I hope that you're using somewhere the variables used for user's input because in the code posted are unused.

The refactored code should look like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FerryMenu {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    addVehicleBooking();

}

public static void addVehicleBooking() {
    String menu_choice = "";
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String booking_ID = "";
    System.out.print("Enter your booking ID");
    booking_ID = input.next();
    String registration = "";
    System.out.print("Enter registration number");
    registration = input.next();
    String make_model = "";
    System.out.print("Enter vehicle make/model");
    make_model = input.next();
    int number_passengers = 1;
    System.out.print("Enter number of passengers");
    number_passengers = scan.nextInt();

    while (!"X".equals(menu_choice)) {
        System.out.println("*** Ferry Ticketing System Menu ***");
        System.out.println("A   -   Add Vehicle Booking");
        System.out.println("B   -   Display Booking Info");
        System.out.println("C   -   Update Insurance Status");
        System.out.println("D   -   Display Booking Summary");
        System.out.println("X   -   Exit");
        System.out.print("Enter your selection: ");
        menu_choice = input.next();
    }

}

}
```